# SpriteRenderer shows stripe artifacts in build

Tags: unity, rendering, sprites

The sprite renderer can render the sprite correctly in the Unity Play mode, but when I build the game, it can't render the sprite correctly, and there are stripes on the sprite.

Here are the screenshots(on the top are sprites rendered in the Unity embedded play mode(expected), at the bottom are sprites rendered in the Unity build mode):

[image: sprite rendered in Unity embedded play mode]
[image: sprite rendered in Unity embedded play mode]

[image: sprite rendered in Unity Build mode]
[image: sprite rendered in Unity Build mode]

I've tried to lower the resolution ratio of the image. For example, 1000x1000 down to 200x200. Then I replace the high resolution one and reduce the Pixels Per Unit to match. It can fix the problem, but only works for some of the sprites without animation. And for the sprite with animation, when I disable the animator, it looks correct, but when I enable the animator, the problem happens in some of the frames of the animation, so the animation looks weird.

Comment: This looks like what you get when code tries to read an image with the wrong stride (for example, treating a 64 pixel wide image as though it were 32 pixels wide, so each row of the output is made of the two halves of one row of input). Nothing you do in the Unity editor should cause this, so suspect #1 is that your Unity installation itself is corrupted somehow. I'd recommend uninstalling, and installing an updated LTS version. Be sure to also describe in your question what platform you're building for, and what build settings you're using.

Comment: I'm trying to build the Windows x86-64 version and use the Default Compression Method. By the way, I've used 2019.4.40f1c1 and 2019.4.36f1c1 to build this, and all of these have the same issue.

Comment: If it's persisting after a re-install, my next step would be to make a minimal project demonstrating the issue in the most up to date LTS version and report it to Unity as a bug. I've never been able to reproduce anything like this when building for Windows.

Comment: Updating your graphics card drivers is also worth a try.

Comment: Thanks, it fixes when I level up the Unity Editor to 2021.3.6f1c1. And It is weird when I build a new 2019.4.40f1c1 demo and create animation with the same art resources to repeat the bug, the bug just disappeared.

Comment: Very strange! Sounds like your original 2019.4 project may be corrupted somehow. Try making a copy of that project, and delete the Library folder, then try again — it might be you had a corrupted asset cached. If that doesn't work, delete content from the copy until the problem vanishes — that should help narrow down whether some script or asset in that project is the cause. This can help you build a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. If you succeed at reproducing the problem this way, edit your question to include the steps to recreate it.